# Sony Vaio Ricoh Webcam not working

Tags: webcam, vaio, sony

I've been stumped by this for a couple of days now trying to get my webcam on my laptop working with my Ubuntu. It is a dual booted Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 if that matters for anything. My webcam works fine in my windows, but isn't detected in my Ubuntu.

Here is my lsusb output for the camera

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ca:18ff Ricoh Co., Ltd
```

I've tried the instructions here and all I get is https://launchpad.net/~r5u87x-loader/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

```
Downloading firmware...
Installing...
Loading firmware into your camera...
r5u87x firmware loader v0.2

Searching for device...

Error: Failed to find any supported webcams.
```

I'm not exactly sure how this firmware loader works, but I don't think that my 05ca:18ff camera is in that. Because when I look at the output after trying this 
http://www.nosinmiubuntu.com/2010/10/webcam-r5u870-en-ubuntu-1010-maverick.html

My output after typing

```
sudo make install
```

is this

```
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1803.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1803.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1810.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1810.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1812.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1812.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1830.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1830.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1832.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1832.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1833.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1833.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1834.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1834.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1835.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1835.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1836.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1836.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1837.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1837.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1839.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1839.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-183a.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-183a.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-183b.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-183b.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-183e.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-183e.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1841.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1841.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1870_1.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1870_1.fw
install -m 0644 ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1870.fw /usr/lib/r5u87x/ucode/r5u87x-05ca-1870.fw
```

And my 05ca:18ff isn't in that list, so is that the problem? And if that's the problem then what can I do for that?

Comment: Could you do a `hardinfo --generate-report > /tmp/hardinfo.txt` and add `/tmp/hardinfo.txt` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back here?

Comment: This is what I got! http://paste.ubuntu.com/9701481/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say but you're affected by [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/120434) that has existed since 2007 so I would stop looking for a solution and buy a camera that is compatible with Linux.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 6 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you very much, but this webcam is built into my laptop screen, is there anyway of replacing that?

Comment: How technical are you?  (I wouldn't bother, disable it in the BIOS or blacklist the module and add a USB one that has a Linux compatible logo)

Comment: I'm fairly technical, and I'm always trying to learn more and more. Yeah, I have an external webcam that's actually pretty good, I just get annoyed having to carry it around with my laptop, which is why I wanted to use my internal one

Comment: There is normally an internal USB bus inside a laptop.  Download the Service Manual for your laptop (they can be found on the web) and for your camera (probably nothing) disassemble both and assemble them back! (*if and only if* the measurements match!)